# Finding a curve orthogonally equidistant between two curves.

Tags: differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, computational-geometry, differential

I have two curves, $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ which meet at $(x_0, 0)$ and $(x_1, 0)$, these curves as such form a closed shape, but not necessarily a convex one. I would like to generate a curve $f_c(x)$ between the two whose (euclidean) distance orthogonal to the curve itself is equal between the two outer curves. Clearly the average of the two functions is not the answer. It seems to me the best guess is a 2nd order ODE, 2 point BVP, similar to a strom-liouville problem, based on the evolution of the $f_c(x)$ beginning at $(x_0, 0)$, but I am unsure of the exact expression of the ODE.

Comment: This seems to depend on the speeds you move on the given curves.

Comment: It is not clear to me exactly what you mean here. Are you talking about the curves $y = f_1(x)$ and $y = f_2(x)$, or are $f_1$ and $f_2$ themselves curves into $\Bbb R^2$? Do you want $f_c(x)$ to necessarily be half-way between $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ for each $x$, or just that if we move on the orthogonal line through $f_c(x)$, it is the same distance to the first point where the line intersects each of the $f_i$, anywhere along them?

Comment: I have two curves, $f_1(x)$ and $f_2(x)$ in $R^2$. I want to define an $f_c(x)$ such that if I travel orthogonal to the curve at each point the other two curves are equidistant. I.e. if i travel in the orthogonal direction in the direction of the center of curvature its a distance of d to $f_1(x)$ and if I travel away from the center of curvature its the same distance d to $f_2(x)$. Hope this clarifies it.